# AppleScript Read The Keywords In The Preview App

Tags: pdf, applescript

The Preview App on the Mac lets you add keywords to a PDF file.

Is it possible to use AppleScript to read the keywords?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The Exiftool manages keywords for many file types, including PDF. This is a free command line tool you can download. Once the tool is installed, you can use it via Terminal or, of course, via Applescript with "do shell script".

If myFile is the PDF file selected, then you can read the existing keywords with:

```
set myKeyWords to do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -Keywords " & quoted form of (POSIX path myFile)
if length of myKeyWords > 35 then
        set myKeyWords to text 35 thru -1 of myKeyWords 
end if
```

The result of the command is empty (if no keywords) or it is made of 33 spaces, ':', 1 space, and the list of keywords separated by ','. This is why I added the 'if' statement after the do shell script command.

And you can also write new keywords (variable MyKey) in your PDF file with :

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool -Keywords+='" & MyKey & "' -Overwrite_Original " & quoted form of (POSIX path of myFile)
```

Exiftool can do many other things for images and PDF files. Some actions are specific to images, some to PDF, or for all file types. Please use the man page in Terminal to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Preview.app supports only the generic classes / commands and has no application specific dictionary.

It might be possible with the ugly GUI scripting.